# How do I use "Or" in a If statement VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

Hello I am trying to make a simple login with multiple accounts. I keep getting System.InvalidCastException.

```
     If ViTextBox1.Text = "user1" Or "user2" And ViTextBox2.Text = "pass1" Or "pass2" Then
        MsgBox("Log In Succesful")
        ViTextBox1.Text = "Username"
        ViTextBox2.Text = "Password"
        Me.Hide()
        Form2.Show()
    Else
        MsgBox("Wrong Username Or Password!")
        ViTextBox2.Text = ""
    End If
```

Comment: Try this: If (ViTextBox1.Text = "user1" Or ViTextBox1.Text = "user2") And (ViTextBox2.Text = "pass1" Or ViTextBox2.Text = "pass2") Then ... but if user1 enters pass2 will login anyway, you should hava a collection in which each user has its own password

Comment: It uses *expressions*.  `(ViTextBox1.Text = "user1")` is an expression, "user2" is not. See [Or Operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/06s37a7f.aspx)

Comment: Thanks! I am new to VB. This really helped. How do I mark this as "Solved"?

Comment: Are you sure of this logic? Do you really want _user1_ be able to login with _pass1_  or _pass2_

Comment: Well not really. But I have no clue or how to make data collections for login data.

Comment: Surely it should be `IF (ViTextBox1.Text = "user1" AND viTextbox2="pass1") OR (ViTextBox1.Text = "user2" AND viTextbox2="pass2")`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will fix the problem Steve described, nest the tests so you can explicityly say User1 must be Pass1 and User2 must be Pass2:

```
If (ViTextBox1.Text = "user1" And ViTextBox2.Text = "pass1") Or (ViTextBox1.Text = "user2" And ViTextBox2.Text = "pass2") Then
```

Comment: `And` and `Or` are bitwise operators. Logiacal operators in the vb.net are `AndAlso` and `OrElse`